# Error when factorial recursion reaches zero

Tags: perl, function, recursion, error-handling, parameter-passing

Why does the following recursive factorial fails in Perl, even if it works in C++ and Java?

Java:

```java
public static long factorial(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return factorial(n-1) * n;
  }
}
```

C++:

```cpp
long factorial(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

But this one fails in Perl (`use Carp;`):

```perl
sub factorial {
    my $n = shift || croak "null value for argument";
    return 1 if $n == 0;  # base case
    return  $n * factorial($n-1);
}
```

Error message (line 10 is where the function is called in `main()`, line 16 is the second `return` statement):

```
 null value for argument at ./fact1.pl line 14.
        main::factorial(0) called at ./fact1.pl line 16
        main::factorial(1) called at ./fact1.pl line 10
```

(The following has been edited thanks to Matt Jacob pointing out my omission in the original version.)

The original version, without carp, but with `|| return`, the error message was:

```
Use of uninitialized value in multiplication (*) at ./fact1.pl line 16.
```

which was the result of an attempt to make the script silent when there was no command line argument. (No complaint about `uninitialized value`.)

A small modification of the base case makes it work in Perl too:

```perl
sub factorial {
    my $n = shift || croak "null value for argument";
    return 1 if $n == 1;  # base case
    return $n * factorial($n-1);
}
```

(Of course, at the expense of doing away with handling `0` (zero) input.)

---

**Lessons Learnt**

1. The problem was at a different location where I thought

   - the Perl code had the error in the part that it attempted to do more than the C++ or Java code snippets (a really crude approach)
   - the different error messages should have given me  a hint
2. The following could have helped me localise the issue:

   - delete all after `shift;`
   - remember that `0` (zero) means `false`
3. [Logical Defined-Or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) exists in Perl since version 5.10
4. As for proper error handling, [this page](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/11/14/exception.html) provides a good overview.

Comment: Reply to "why not the same if/else": The java is from a course example. (so the braces). C++, my test after Perl had failed. (but I like to do away with braces for simple expressions).
In Perl, the equivalent "no braces" solution is when the conditional clause comes last.

Comment: Your statement about the error message prior to using `croak` does not match the code in your question. If you called `factorial()`, `$n` would be `undef`, and the warning would be about "uninitialized $n in numeric eq". (But `undef` would implicitly get converted to 0, and the function would still return 1.) The real question is: why are you calling the function with an undefined/null value and expecting it to work in Perl when it wouldn't work in other languages!

Comment: @MattJacob you are  absolutely right. it was not simply "without" but with "|| return". It was meant to help me when there was  no command line argument. (I am going to edit the question and add your comment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has some rather unorthodox rules for what is considered true.

In particularly, the number 0 is considered to be false when used in a Boolean expression. So when you say this

```
my $n = shift || croak "null value for argument";
```

If `shift` pulls 0 as the argument, then it gets seen as false, which means the `||` operator needs to evaluate its second operand.

Fortunately, the writers of Perl anticipated this sort of use case, so they defined an alternative or-operator. Whereas `||` checks whether the first value is truthy, `//` checks whether the first value is defined.

```
my $n = shift // croak "null value for argument";
```

This will do what you intend, unless there is the possibility that `$n` is the literal value `undef`. In that case, you'll need some more complex introspection to check whether the argument exists, but for the purposes of this factorial function, this should suffice.

Comment: You might also add that `//` and `||` have a higher binding than `or`, so in fact the `$n = shift || croak` actually assigns the return value of `croak` to `$n`. Since `croak` is a `die`, there's no return value because it never returns, but this still matters.

Comment: @simbabque, You're warning us that Perl is actually doing exactly what we want it to do. When using `or`, the assignment needlessly happens, and we indirectly examine what we want to examine by examining the result of the assignment.  When using `||` or `//`, the actual thing that needs to be checked is checked, and the assignment *doesn't* needlessly happen as with `or`. That's actually the ideal situation, not something to be warned about!

Comment: It seemed to be a curious omission in the tutorials and  materials I used that they did not have this operator, so I made a little historical search. The _defined-or_ operator (//), as it is called in the book (Learning Perl, 5th Edition) where I managed to find it first, was introduced with Perl 5.10.

Comment: Reference to the relevant help page (and bookmark) under the name [logical defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).